# Width of TableView in SplitViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

So I'm working to convert my iPhone app to universal. For the MasterController in my UISplitViewController which is basically is just the same TableViewController on my App I am trying to add an image to the middle of the tableview when there are no entries. I am still working with Spring and Struts rather than the AutoLayout.

However when I load tableview on my iPad it's off center.

I do an NSLog of the `frame = [self.tableview frame]` and I get the values:

`[6148:c07] Width: 748.000000
[6148:c07] Height: 1024.000000
[6148:c07] X: 20.000000
[6148:c07] Y: 0.000000`
It's basically giving the whole iPad dimension... I did this to an empty iPad application with a master/detail and it does the same thing... weird

Why is the width 748?

In my iPad Storyboard it's showing Width 320 and Height 704?

Thanks!

Comment: The 748 is because there's 20-pixel status bar. But it should be subtracted from the height, like 1004.

Comment: @ott- but thereit shouldn't be that size. It gives me the entire iPad screen size rather than just the tableview dimensions.

Comment: Oh, I got that wrong. The tableview is really a subview of the master. NSLog() with `[tableview description]` show framesize and parent?